# Accessing key field into Django Template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

How can I access key field of model into django template?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

`**key**` should be the name of the attribute you are expecting to find in the `blockedsoftwares_list`

So, assuming your `blockedsoftwares_list`contain a list of `key` (then the choice of the variable name is not explicit), you want to check that the `key` field of the current `software` is not in the blocked software **key** list:

```
{% for software in softwares %}
   {% if software.key not in blockedsoftwareskeys %}
      {{ software.name }}<br />
      {{ software.version }}<br />
      {{ software.description }}<br />
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Assuming this is the wanted behavior (please be more specific by editing your question), then why giving the whole query set to your template when django orm allows you to use filters in the view ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions:

1. You should filter the data before passing it into view
2. You can write additional function in model for retrieving the key if it`s not a field already

Can you explain exactly what is `**__key__**` ?

Comment: I think the OP used `**__key__**` in order to get bold text in the code snippet, but that it's precisely what he is asking for : what should be at that place

Comment: Without clarification or move extended example (maybe the code of model) it\`s quite hard to make the proper answer.